# How to create an endpoint with 2 path params. AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-gateway

I have an url in such format: `resource_1/{id_1}/resource_2/{id_2}/assign`.

I know how to create a simple proxy resource with 1 path param. But in my case I got two.

So I decided to create it one by one, at first `resource_1/{id_1}/` and then expand it to `resource_2/{id_2}/assign` and as you see on picture, action **Create Resourcce** is blocked on initial proxy resource.

How can I solve this issue to have endpoint with 2 path params?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your `id+` is a [proxy resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-set-up-simple-proxy.html), as indicated by the `+` sign.

From the doc :

> API Gateway defines a proxy resource as a placeholder for a resource
>   to be specified when the request is submitted. A proxy resource is
>   expressed by a special path parameter of {proxy+}, often referred to
>   as a greedy path parameter. The + sign indicates whichever child
>   resources are appended to it. The /parent/{proxy+} placeholder stands
>   for any resource matching the path pattern of /parent/*. The greedy
>   path parameter name, proxy, can be replaced by another string in the
>   same way you treat a regular path parameter name.

Remove the `+` sign from your parameter name and you will be allowed to create sub resources.

Comment: great it helped.  Once tested, do not forget to accept the answer :-)